# Give a counterexample for the following statement:

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

i) boundary of the set $S$ is the same as the boundary of the interior of $S$

This is clearly false, but I couldn't think of any example? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Hint: try out a singleton (containing a non-isolated point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There exist non-empty sets that have an empty interior

Comment: then boundary would be the real numbers themselves!, great thanks!

Comment: Huh?  I guess you've decided to take $S = \Bbb Q$.  That wasn't what I meant, but sure, it works.

Comment: wouldn't the boundary of $\emptyset$ be real numbers?

Comment: No: the boundary of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

If  you  have  an  isolated  point?

Comment: If that isolated point is contained in $S$ then interior of $S$ wouldn't contain the isolated point since no open ball around the isolated point contains elements of $S$ only.